# rust syntax match binding - how to match "Some" with condition and None together

Tags: rust

I'm trying to match like this (or would also consider using let binding since the other case isn't interesting to me)

```
let cl : Option<u64> = res.content_length();
match cl {
  Some(x) if x == 0 | None => { // want to take care of x == 0 or None cases
    return std::result::Result::Ok(RegisterResponse{..Default::default()})
  }
  _ => {} // don't care
}
```

I'm getting this compilation error

```
 Some(x) if x == 0 | None => {
    |                                       ^ no implementation for `{integer} | std::option::Option<_>`
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the match syntax [doesn't support it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=801a824f32e02d18309b0043a2d29938). Your specific case may be handled with the inverse though: `match { Some(x) if x != 0 { /* do nothing */ }, _ => { return ...; } }`

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `:` after `cl` in `let cl Option<u64> = res.content_length();`

also, you need ',' before `_ => {}` (after `}`)

Comment: that was just a typo